# stop: unknown instance

Tags: ros, turtlebot, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Relatively new turtlebot user.
I had a clean Ubuntu 11.10 install to my turtlebot laptop (a HP Mini). I
installed ROS electric  following the instructions here: 
http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Install
I changed  ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME on laptop and rebooted.
I get the following when trying to stop turtlebot service

```
turtlebot@turtlebot1:~$ sudo service turtlebot stop
stop: Unknown instance:
```

Next, I started turtlebot service.
I can start as many instances as I want without any warning:

```
turtlebot@turtlebot1:~$ sudo service turtlebot start
turtlebot start/running, process 2089
turtlebot@turtlebot1:~$ sudo service turtlebot start
turtlebot start/running, process 2247
turtlebot@turtlebot1:~$ sudo service turtlebot start
turtlebot start/running, process 2405
```

Although turtlebot service is started (3 times) communication with master fails:

```
turtlebot@Turtlebot-WS:~$ rostopic echo /diagnostics
ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!
```

My problem is similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/12933/turtlebot-upstart-install-failure 
That one was solved by installing daemontools. It was installed at this step:
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot-robot
during ROS installation.

What is missing?

Before you ask, ouput of **ps axuf**

```
turtlebot@turtlebot1:~$ ps auxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:02  \_ [ksoftirqd/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [migration/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [migration/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:0]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [ksoftirqd/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [cpuset]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [khelper]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [netns]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [sync_supers]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [bdi-default]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [kintegrityd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [kblockd]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [ata_sff]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [khubd]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [md]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/1:1]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [khungtaskd]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kswapd0]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   17:42   0:00  \_ [ksmd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   17:42   0:00  \_ [khugepaged]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [fsnotify_mark]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [crypto]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [kthrotld]
root       107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:01  \_ [kworker/0:2]
root       202  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_0]
root       203  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_1]
root       204  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_2]
root       205  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [scsi_eh_3]
root       206  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/u:4]
root       215  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [kworker/u:5]
root       233  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [jbd2/sda1-8]
root       234  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       562  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [kpsmoused]
root       685  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [hd-audio0]
root       893  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [l2cap]
root       900  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   17:42   0:00  \_ [krfcommd]
root      1006  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ [flush-8:0]
root      1851  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    17:56   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:0]
root      2080  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    18:02   0:00  \_ [kworker/0:1]
root         1  0.0  0.1   3336  1828 ?        Ss   17:42   0:01 /sbin/init
root       288  0.0  0.0   2656   608 ?        S    17:42   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       292  0.0  0.1   3108  1412 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       399  0.0  0.0   3104  1016 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
root       400  0.0  0.0   3104   960 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ udevd --daemon
syslog     491  0.0  0.1  29024  1584 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 rsyslogd -c5
root       494  0.0  0.2   6432  2316 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      1852  0.0  0.3   9832  3224 ?        Ss   17:56   0:00  \_ sshd: turtlebot [priv]
1000      1976  0.0  0.1   9832  1644 ?        S    17:56   0:00      \_ sshd: turtlebot@pts/1
1000      1977  0.2  0.6  10716  6884 pts/1    Ss   17:56   0:01          \_ -bash
1000      2559  0.0  0.1   5136  1096 pts/1    R+   18:05   0:00              \_ ps auxf
103        507  0.3  0.2   4360  2084 ?        Ss   17:42   0:05 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
root       529  0.0  0.2   6872  2808 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
avahi      532  0.0  0.1   3324  1712 ?        S    17:42   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [turtlebot1.local]
avahi      533  0.0  0.0   3324   436 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root       534  0.0  0.5  29236  5992 ?        Ssl  17:42   0:00 NetworkManager
root      1445  0.0  0.1   2744  1228 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ /sbin/dhclient -d -4 -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -p
root       552  0.0  0.3  23472  3624 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
root       582  0.0  0.2   5696  2396 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
root       730  0.0  0.0   2660   348 ?        S    17:42   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       739  0.0  0.0   1976   528 tty4     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
root       744  0.0  0.0   1976   532 tty5     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
root       756  0.0  0.0   1976   532 tty2     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root       758  0.0  0.0   1976   532 tty3     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
root       763  0.0  0.0   1976   528 tty6     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root       769  0.0  0.0   1992   708 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
root       770  0.0  0.0   3428   620 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance
root       772  0.0  0.0   2436   888 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 cron
daemon     773  0.0  0.0   2288   348 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 atd
root       822  0.0  0.3  41028  3652 ?        Ssl  17:42   0:00 lightdm
root       895  1.0  0.9  18728  9172 tty7     Ss+  17:42   0:14  \_ /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitc
1000      1124  0.0  0.8  47472  8556 ?        Ssl  17:42   0:00  \_ /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
1000      1158  0.0  0.0   3864   180 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/
1000      1183  0.1  1.4 124024 14660 ?        Sl   17:42   0:02      \_ /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
1000      1296  2.5  5.1 173420 52048 ?        Sl   17:42   0:35      \_ compiz
1000      1386  0.0  0.0   2048   512 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00      |   \_ /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/compiz-decorator
1000      1387  0.0  0.9  22432  9452 ?        S    17:42   0:00      |       \_ /usr/bin/unity-window-decorator
1000      1322  0.0  0.7  46392  7440 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-fallback-mount-helper
1000      1323  0.0  1.2  88832 12644 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ nm-applet
1000      1324  0.0  0.9  52436  9464 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ bluetooth-applet
1000      1326  0.0  0.5  29372  6064 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
1000      1327  0.1  2.0  84656 20660 ?        Sl   17:42   0:02      \_ nautilus -n
1000      1375  0.0  0.3  26504  3568 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ telepathy-indicator
1000      1443  0.0  0.7  22344  7672 ?        S    17:42   0:00      \_ /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
1000      1496  0.0  0.4  50996  4420 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00      \_ zeitgeist-datahub
1000      1514  0.0  1.6  38456 17212 ?        S    17:42   0:00      \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
1000      1646  0.0  1.0  49064 11116 ?        Sl   17:43   0:00      \_ update-notifier
1000      1845  0.0  0.3  33404  3572 ?        Sl   17:44   0:00      \_ /usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
root       885  0.0  0.1   4504  1560 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
root       959  0.0  0.0   2504  1012 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/chronyd
root      1021  0.0  0.3  15776  3296 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root      1048  0.0  0.0   1976   536 tty1     Ss+  17:42   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1051  0.0  0.3  27820  3300 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
1000      1161  0.0  0.0   3756   492 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubu
1000      1162  0.5  0.2   6152  2652 ?        Ss   17:42   0:07 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
1000      1164  0.0  0.2   9156  2348 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
1000      1169  0.0  0.2  31596  2300 ?        Ssl  17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/turtlebot/.gvfs
1000      1181  0.0  0.3  44508  3332 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
root      1192  0.0  0.3  27044  3784 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
root      1228  0.0  0.2   7324  2848 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -F
1000      1274  0.0  0.2   9392  2888 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconfd-2
1000      1280  0.0  0.3  47108  3864 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
colord    1301  0.0  0.9  50920 10080 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/colord/colord
1000      1304  0.0  0.7  38628  7956 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver --no-daemon
1000      1310  0.0  0.0   3532   788 ?        S    17:42   0:01 syndaemon -i 0.5 -K -R
1000      1313  0.0  0.1   8216  1968 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
1000      1316  0.0  0.5  98592  5712 ?        S<l  17:42   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
1000      1330  0.0  0.2  13272  2548 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/pulseaudio/pulse/gconf-helper
rtkit     1318  0.0  0.1  19096  1220 ?        SNl  17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon
1000      1338  0.0  0.3  10060  3308 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
root      1342  0.0  0.3  22972  3468 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks/udisks-daemon
root      1343  0.0  0.0   6328   736 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ udisks-daemon: not polling any devices
1000      1348  0.0  0.2  31372  2444 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/d-conf/dconf-service
1000      1353  0.0  1.1  55476 12132 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
1000      1355  0.0  0.2  19328  2236 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
1000      1359  0.0  0.2   9244  2164 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
1000      1367  0.0  0.3   9716  3072 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.1 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
1000      1371  0.0  0.2   9188  2504 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawner :1.1 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/1
1000      1377  0.0  0.3   9124  3084 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
1000      1390  0.0  0.9  44132  9260 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/bamf/bamfdaemon
1000      1393  0.2  1.5  82096 15404 ?        Sl   17:42   0:03 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
1000      1400  0.0  0.5 124124  5832 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
1000      1404  0.0  0.4  50728  4152 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-application/indicator-application-service
1000      1406  0.0  0.6  77244  6544 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
1000      1411  0.0  0.5  63652  5272 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
1000      1415  0.0  0.4  70132  5060 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/indicator-session/indicator-session-service
1000      1437  0.0  0.2   7740  2324 ?        S    17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/geoclue/geoclue-master
1000      1502  0.0  1.3  33540 13636 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
1000      1503  0.0  0.0   4292   248 ?        S    17:42   0:00  \_ /bin/cat
1000      1532  0.0  0.4  52596  4088 ?        Sl   17:43   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-lens-music/unity-music-daemon
1000      1534  0.0  0.4  52184  4172 ?        Sl   17:43   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-lens-files/unity-files-daemon
1000      1536  0.1  0.6  58064  6460 ?        Sl   17:43   0:01 /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon
1000      1600  0.0  0.2  49940  2568 ?        Sl   17:43   0:00 /usr/lib/unity-lens-music/unity-musicstore-daemon
root      1661  0.0  0.8  17336  8432 ?        S    17:43   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33198/stop:-unknown-instance/) by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-05-04**:
Did you run the "sudo ./install.bash wlan0" command? If so, does wlan0 have an IP? (If it doesn't, the service will probably not start ROS)

**Comment by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) on 2012-05-07**:
Yes. I  run sudo ./install.bash wlan0 command. But that didnt help. With a clean (and more stable) installation, everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wiped clean everything.

Installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid) + ROS Diamondback

So far, I am not getting this error.

This is not a good solution, but it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Ozkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2258/ozkan/) with karma: 38 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0